# It's been about five months since me and my wife applied for a UK resident permit

Tags: united-kingdom, residency

Me and my wife, a French National, applied for a UK residence but, until now, nothing. It's going on five months and all we have gotten is an email stating that the application is received. I later got a letter from the home office for my biometric but since then nothing. Please could you advise on what to do next.

Comment: What is your nationality? Under what premises did you apply? Have you heard back since. Your question is unclear as of now and likely also too broad.